# Using sed to replace IP using regex

Tags: regex, macos, sed

Assuming a simple text file:

```
123.123.123.123
```

I would like to replace the IP inside of it with `222.222.222.222`. I have tried the below but nothing changes, however the same regex seems to work [in this Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/39v40)

```
sed -i '' 's/(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/222.222.222.222/' file.txt
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: That makes no difference. But I don't see why the global flag would make a difference in a bare file sans the one IP address :/

Comment: BSD sed doesn't support `\d`. Use a POSIX character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

- sed doesn't like PCRE digit property `\d`, use range: `[0-9]` or POSIX `[[:digit:]]`
- You need to use `-r` flag for extended regex as well.

This should work:

```
s='123.123.123.123'
sed -r 's/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/222.222.222.222/' <<< "$s"
222.222.222.222
```

Better would be to use anchors to avoid matching unexpected input:

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/222.222.222.222/' <<< "$s"
```

**PS:** On OSX use `-E` instead of `-r`:

```
sed -E 's/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/222.222.222.222/' <<< "$s"
222.222.222.222
```

Comment: I can replace `\d` with the integer range, but OSX sed doesn't seem to have `-r` as a flag

Comment: Added an option for OSX, i.e. using `-E`

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use `-r`, as indicated by anubhava.

But in case you don't have it, you have to escape every single `(`, `)`, `{` and `}`. And also, use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`:

```
$ sed 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/222.222.222.222/' <<< "123.123.123.123"
222.222.222.222
```